# Is it poor practice to identify object types via an enumeration property, instead of using GetType()?

Tags: c#, types, interface, enums

I have a collection of objects that all implement one (custom) interface: `IAuditEvent`.

Each object can be stored in a database and a unique numeric id is used for each object type.

The method that stores the objects loops around a `List<IAuditEvent>`, so it needs to know the specific type of each object in order to store the correct numeric id.

**Is it poor practice to have an enumeration property on `IAuditEvent` so that each object can identify its type with a unique enumeration value?**

I can see that the simplest solution would be to write a method that translates a `Type` into an integer, but what if I need an enumeration of audit events for another purpose? Would it still be wrong to have my enumeration property on `IAuditEvent`?

Comment: Why would it be poor practice to have a member of `IAuditEvent` to identify the particular kind of event? What are the potential issues?

Comment: Ha ha! Well that's what I'm asking. ;-) I think some people would argue that you're giving the object 2 different ways to identify itself, and those 2 ways could potentially disagree.

Comment: What do you mean with "identify objects via an enumeration property"? GetType() could be used to identify the type of an object, not to identify the object itself...

Comment: Thanks @user1027167. I have clarified my question.

Comment: The purpose of implementing an interface is to abstract away the implementation - IOW you use the interface and don't care about the implementing type, therefore there should be no need to identify it with an enum value.

Comment: @slugster - I do need some way of linking a unique ID to each type though. What do you suggest?

Comment: @James, i've added an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This database type id (or discriminator) is essentially metadata of each type. Mixing data and metadata on each instance isn't great. My preferred solution would be to write a custom attribute to hold this metadata, apply it to each type, and read these using the `GetCustomAttributes` method of `Type`.

```
[DatabaseDiscriminator(123)]
public class MyAuditEvent : IAuditEvent
{
}
```

Comment: What happens if a developer forgets to add the custom attribute though? Can you catch that at compile time?

Comment: No, it would have to be a runtime exception. I don't think that's a huge drawback though. After all, a developer could implement an interface but leave the appropriate method as `throw new NotImplementedException()`.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Could I use reflection to check that every object that implements `IAuditEvent` has a custom attribute? My application already runs a series of "self-tests" (more focused around database configuration, but there's no reason why it couldn't check this too).

Comment: Yes, although you might want to think about starting a unit test project to capture this sort of thing as you don't necessarily want to run much of this on startup.

Comment: "you might want to think about starting a unit test project" - good point.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because this is the approach that I've decided to take.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's bad. You are now assuming that every implementation of `IAudit` knows about the other implementations, because they should all have a unique ID; furthermore you need to add a new value to the `enum` for every new instance of the interface. This is just extra information that isn't needed inside the application but just in the data representation.

Rather have a lookup table in your business layer:

```
new Dictionary<Type, int> {
    { typeof(UserAudit), 1 },
    { typeof(OrderAudit), 2 }
}
```

Comment: "Yes it's bad" - I thought it might be!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: it depends.

Remember what interfaces are for. The entire point of them is to hide the implementation to the users of the interface. When it comes to interfaces i see two types of code:

Code that **uses** the interface. This code should only know about IAuditEvent, and not its implementing classes. If this code needs to know about different types of audit events (i mean "type" in the most general sense, not classes specifically), then i'd say it's good practice to add a Type property to IAuditEvent. As far as the user is concerned, there does not even need to be a different implementation for each type.

The other type of code is code that **implements** the interface, and i mean not just classes that inherit from IAuditEvent but also classes that construct and are meant to work with these implementations directly. If *this and only this* code needs to know what type of IAuditEvent it is dealing with (and here i mean type as in class), then i'd say it is bad practice to add a Type property, since it exposes bits of the implementation. This code could just as well do a instanceof check.

Comment: A useful reply, thank you. I'm starting to wonder if I might be tackling my problem in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of implementing an interface is to abstract away the implementation - IOW you use the interface and don't care about the implementing type, therefore there should be no need to identify it with an enum value.

Having said that, the way I would do it is to have a common base type which both implements the interface and has an abstract property that returns the enum:

```
public abstract class BaseType : IAuditEvent
{
    public abstract MyTypeEnum TypeId { get; }

    ... add any base implementation of the interface ...
}
```

then in each deriving object:

```
public class MyConcreteType : BaseType 
{
    public MyTypeEnum TypeId { get { return MyTypeEnum.SpecificValue; } }

    ... any overrides, etc ....
}
```

This approach has a couple of advantages:

- it keeps your code clean. When implementing the interface in a number of classes there is a good chance that there will be some common implementation of the interface that the different objects can share, that can go in the base class. Make judicious use of `abstract` and `virtual` methods/properties.
- using an enum to identify your objects can help avoid those endless and tedious `if (myObj.GetType() == typeof(ObjectA)) {} else if (myObject.GetType() == typeof(ObjectB))...` statements when it comes time to branch based on the type of the implementor - now you can just use a switch statement based on the enum returned by the TypeId property

You will still be left with the issue of having to extend the enum should you add more implementations, but that is a relatively simple code change, and you have to recomplie anyway if you are adding more implementations (so extending the enum isn't a big deal, but you do want to avoid changing the already assigned values if possible).